# Как организовать перебор использования всех возможных комбинаций классов из списка внутри главного класса?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, python-3.5

Имеется некоторое количество классов, представляющих из себя индикаторы 
для анализа торговых стратегий для игры на фондовом рынке. Для примера пусть это будут скользящие средние.

```
class analyst1:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
    def advise(self):
        seq['shortMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=20).mean(), 2)
        seq['longMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=110).mean(), 2)
        seq['signal'] = np.where(seq['shortMA'] > seq['longMA'], 1, -1)
        return seq['signal']

class analyst2:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
    def advise(self):
        seq['shortMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=18).mean(), 2)
        seq['longMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=99).mean(), 2)
        seq['signal'] = np.where(seq['shortMA'] > seq['longMA'], 1, -1)
        return seq['signal']

class analyst3:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
    def advise(self):
        seq['shortMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=22).mean(), 2)
        seq['longMA'] = round(seq['Close'].rolling(window=121).mean(), 2)
        seq['signal'] = np.where(seq['shortMA'] > seq['longMA'], 1, -1)
        return seq['signal']
```

Каждый из них принимает на вход датасет биржевых котировок.

```
a = web.DataReader('SBER.ME', data_source='yahoo',
start='01/04/2016', end='03/07/2019')
```

И возвращает объект series из 1 (дни с восходящим трендом) и -1 (дни с нисходящим трендом)

```
2019-02-20    1
2019-02-21    1
2019-02-22    1
2019-02-25    1
2019-02-26    1
2019-02-27    1
2019-02-28    1
2019-03-01    1
2019-03-04    1
2019-03-05   -1
2019-03-06   -1
2019-03-07   -1
```

Наконец, есть главный класс, который, собственно и занимается моделированием торговли, с учётом комиссий, стоп-приказов, дивидендных выплат, рисуя графики и т.д. (вопрос не касается этих вещей, поэтому они опущены). Задача класса: найти оптимальную стратегию по конкретному активу, для чего необходим перебор комбинаций индикаторов. Параметр sources - список классов-индикаторов, которые будут подавать сигналы (т.е. в рассматриваемом примере sources = [analyst1, analyst2, analyst3]). Параметр weights - список весовых коэффициентов значимости сигналов от соответствующих индикаторов так, что sum(weights) == 1.

```
class capital_manager:
    def __init__(self, ticker, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.seq = web.DataReader(ticker, start=start, end=end, data_source='yahoo')
    def combine_signals(self, sources, weights):
        self.sources = sources
        self.weights = weights
```

На данном этапе от класса capital_manager требуется только выдавать сумму взвешенных сигналов индикаторов, которые он получил на вход. То есть, для единичного варианта из перебора должно выходить нечто подобное:

```
2019-02-20    0.75
2019-02-21    0.8
2019-02-22    0.75
2019-02-25    0.6
2019-02-26    0.7
2019-02-27    0.6
2019-02-28    0.5
2019-03-01    0.4
2019-03-04    0.1
2019-03-05   -0.5
2019-03-06   -0.6
2019-03-07   -0.7
```

Нужно организовать перебор всех комбинаций индикаторов, то есть включая варианты с одним и двумя из трёх. Как оформить функцию combine_signals, чтобы она объединила все series из комбинаций сигналов в один датафрейм, если допустить weights для двух индикаторов 0.6 и 0.4, а для трёх 0.3, 0.3 и 0.4?

Примерный вид того, что должна возвращать функция combine_signals:

```
2019-02-20    0.75  0.8   1  
2019-02-21    0.8   0.9   1
2019-02-22    0.75  0.7   1
2019-02-25    0.6   0.6   1
2019-02-26    0.7   0.7   1
2019-02-27    0.6   0.6   1
2019-02-28    0.5   0.5   1
2019-03-01    0.4   0.5   1
2019-03-04    0.1   0.3   1
2019-03-05   -0.5   0.2  -1
2019-03-06   -0.6   0.0  -1
2019-03-07   -0.7  -0.2  -1
```

Comment: Все нужные классы отнаследуйте от одного базового BaseAnalyst и все дочерние классы будут доступны с помощью BaseAnalyst.__sublasses__()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример (кусок реального кода) обхода дочерних классов. В данном случае миграция базы SQL.

```
class Init:
    '''Класс миграции базы данных.'''
    _db = DB
    _mig = PostgresqlMigrator(_db)
    _history_table = _MigrateHistory
    _odb = ODB

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def apply(self):
        log.info('Начата миграция: %s', self.__class__.__name__)
        self.mig(mig=self._mig)
        log.debug('Изменения применены.')
        self._mig_childs()

    @classmethod
    def _mig_childs(cls):
        '''Как обходить дочерние классы.'''
        for cc in cls.__subclasses__():
            cc().apply()

    def mig(self, mig):
        pass


class Child1(Init):
    """Дочерний класс."""
    def mig(self, mig):
        """Полезная нагрузка."""
        log.debug('Выполнение миграции')


class Child2(Init):
    """Дочерний класс."""
    def mig(self, mig):
        """Полезная нагрузка."""
        log.debug('Выполнение миграции')


class Child1_1(Child1):
    """Дочерний класс."""
    def mig(self, mig):
        """Полезная нагрузка."""
        log.debug('Выполнение миграции')


def apply_migrations():
    Init().apply()
```